# Docker Run command hangs

Tags: powershell, docker, powershell-ise

begin 4/29/2017 update

```
PS C:\Users\shein> docker run -it ubuntu bash

PS C:\Users\shein> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f358524abd13        ubuntu              "bash"              2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            zen_feynman
PS C:\Users\shein> docker kill $(docker ps -q)
f358524abd13

PS C:\Users\shein> docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
f358524abd13

PS C:\Users\shein> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

PS C:\Users\shein> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              f7b3f317ec73        5 days ago          117 MB
hello-world         latest              48b5124b2768        3 months ago        1.84 kB

PS C:\Users\shein>
```

end 4/29/2017 update

Gosh, I'm new to docker and my recent Docker installation (Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e) on windows 10 was working great for the several images I pulled down (I was delighted!) and then the run command started hanging.

Fortunately, "docker run hello-world" still works but it is the only one that still works.

For example, "docker -it Ubuntu bash" does not run any more and I don't know what changed. After typing "docker -it Ubuntu bash" it just hangs until I hit ^c.

Another example of one that used to work but now also hangs is "docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:latest". I used to get a bash prompt and could compose, compile and run C# programs inside of the docker container. Now it just hangs after I hit the return key on the docker run command.

I have tried killing all the containers and deleting all the images.
See below for the results. "docker run -it ubuntu bash" just hangs again.

Thanks
Siegfried

```
PS C:\Users\shein> docker run -it ubuntu bash
docker : Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
At line:1 char:1
+ docker run -it ubuntu bash
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to find ...latest' locally:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

latest: 
Pulling from library/ubuntu
aafe6b5e13de: 
Pulling fs layer
0a2b43a72660: Pulling fs layer
18bdd1e546d2: 
Pulling fs layer
8198342c3e05: 
Pulling fs layer
f56970a44fd4: 
Pulling fs layer
8198342c3e05: 
Waiting
f56970a44fd4: 
Waiting
0a2b43a72660: 
Download complete
18bdd1e546d2: 
Download complete
8198342c3e05: 
Verifying Checksum
8198342c3e05: Download complete
f56970a44fd4: 
Verifying Checksum
f56970a44fd4: 
Download complete
aafe6b5e13de: 
Verifying Checksum
aafe6b5e13de: Download complete
aafe6b5e13de: 
Pull complete
0a2b43a72660: 
Pull complete
18bdd1e546d2: 
Pull complete
8198342c3e05: 
Pull complete
f56970a44fd4: 
Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f3a61450ae43896c4332bda5e78b453f4a93179045f20c8181043b26b5e79028
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
```

Comment: what is the output for `docker images` and `docker ps -a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case the problem was because I used Powershell ISE.

When I used Powershel regular, it worked fine.

Comment: A complete answer would include a brief explanation about what differences between Powershell and Powershell ISE would cause this behavior.